# I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, now I can't boot Windows 7 anymore

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, now I can't boot Windows 7 anymore. What can I do now?

Comment: Did you install it on the same partition with software such as wubi? Or did you install it on a different partition/hard drive? Or did you just all out format the drive and install ubuntu on it?

Comment: i installed it on a different partition

Answer (score 1):

If you install in the same partition your windows 7 wont work ... If you installed in different partition , try to reinstall grub boot loader